# uitableviewcell uiimage autolayout issue in 4 inch iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I am new in xcode / swift. I am having issue with replacing UIImageView in UITableViewCell in iPhone 4 inch screens. I have embed images in 3 with correct: 640, 750, 1242 pixel width in Assets.xcassets.

TableView and ContentView constrains[Trailing Space to, Leading Space to, Bottom Space to, Top Space to] are done from xCode.

This is how I use UIImageView in tableview cellForRowAt:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let identifier = "reusedCell"
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier)

        if(cell == nil) {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        }

        let image = UIImage(named: "TableView\(indexPath.row)")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        cell?.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true

        return cell!
}
```

[image: Click here to see images are cut from right side]

Images are correctly sized in 4.7, and 5.5 inch iphone screens, but not in iphone 5, 5s and SE.

Any help/advice highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make constraints for `imageView`:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
cell?.addSubview(imageView)
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
// for example
imageView.anchor(topAnchor, left: cell.leftAnchor, bottom: cell.bottomAnchor, right: cell.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
```

Or create a **custom cell**:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let imgView = UIImageView()
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        imgView.clipsToBounds = true


        return imgView
    }()

    func setupViews() {
        addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.anchor(topAnchor, left: cell.leftAnchor, bottom: cell.bottomAnchor, right: cell.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
    }
}
```

Then replace your function ***tableView*** to:

```
let identifier = "reusedCell"
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as ! CustomTableViewCell

        let image = UIImage(named: "TableView\(indexPath.row)")
        cell.imageView.image = image

        return cell!
}
```